# Databinding issues using listbox in vuejs

Tags: jquery, css, vue.js, vuejs2

when I hardcode the select multiple as shown below, the script and css works.

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose shifts..." class="chosen-select" multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
```

The same does not work when i bind the data to a database. I get an empty select box. Sometimes it works when i resize the browser and refresh Code are as follows

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose shifts..." class="chosen-select" multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
    <option v-for="(shift, index) in shifts" v-bind:value="shift.ID_HORAIRE"> {{ shift.DESCRIPTION_HORAIRE }}</option>
</select>
```

I am using a custom multiple select. Here is the [link](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).

Comment: too hard to tell without further information, recreate the problem https://codesandbox.io/s/vue

Comment: @A.Lau https://codesandbox.io/s/9l6k7j815r

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused because you have no `v-model` on your `<select>` if you are trying to load the *selected* value from your database.

Also make sure your code used to retrive selectboxes from runs **prior** to your template rendering, in the created or mounted hooks.

Finally, make sure the data you retrieve is **reactive** (placed into a vuex store, or the data of your component, or a props)

Comment: It does not work even with v-model. I need to resize and refresh the browser. I fetched the data on mounted but also tried created. The data I retrieved is stored in the data part of the component. It does not work.

Comment: Are you using the vue debugger? Is it possible to show the actual code? Your example on codesandbox seems to work fine for me: selection of items works fine.